# How to update an associated object along its main object in one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Declaration` model, and partial `_form`, which is being used in edit/update action. In this partial there is a form definition

```
<%= labelled_form_for([@project, @declaration], html: { multipart: false, id: 'declaration_form', class: 'tabular', remote: request.xhr? }) do |f| %>`
```

There is an associated model `DeclarationAnswer`. How can I display attributes of this model, and update them using that main form? `Declaration` has many `DeclarationAnswer`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
Ive added this to the main form

```
    <%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'answers_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
```

And created appropriate partial, defining there its own form